# How can I add an if else conditional statement to this function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How can a modify this function so if the user enters less than 2500 cubic ft the price is equal to 0?

```
function updateCombustibleMaterialFireFee(cubicft) {
    var price = 42;
    if (cubicft > 5000) {
        price += (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
    } 

    // Change the parameters to the correct fee code, fee schedule, etc.
    // updateFee(fcode, fsched, fperiod, fqty, finvoice, pDuplicate, pFeeSeq)
    updateFee("FPERMIT47","FIRE","FINAL",price,"N","N");

    logDebug("$" + price);
}
```

Comment: Um add `} else if () {}`???

Comment: else if (cubicft <2500) {price = 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function updateCombustibleMaterialFireFee(cubicft) 
{
    var price;
    if(cubicft > 5000)
        price = 42 + (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
    else if(cubicft < 2500)
        price = 0;
    else
        price = 42;
    // Change the parameters to the correct fee code, fee schedule, etc.
    // updateFee(fcode, fsched, fperiod, fqty, finvoice, pDuplicate, pFeeSeq)
    updateFee("FPERMIT47","FIRE","FINAL",price,"N","N");
    logDebug("$" + price);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tspa7tuk/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
function updateCombustibleMaterialFireFee(cubicft) {
    var price = 42;
    if (cubicft < 2500) {
        price = 0;
    }
    else if (cubicft > 5000) {
        price += (cubicft - 5000) / 1000 * 22;
    }

    // Change the parameters to the correct fee code, fee schedule, etc.
    // updateFee(fcode, fsched, fperiod, fqty, finvoice, pDuplicate, pFeeSeq)
    updateFee("FPERMIT47", "FIRE", "FINAL", price, "N", "N");

    logDebug("$" + price);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(cubicft<2500){
price = 0;
}else if (cubicft > 5000) {
  enter code here  price += (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is if you want to check if the user entered less than 2500 and the price is equal to 0. It wasn't clear to me if you wanted to set the price to 0

```
if(cubicft < 2500 && price == 0){
    //do something
}
```

if you want to change the price variable you could do something like this :

`price = cubicft < 2500 ? 0 : price`

[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Translates to:

```
var price = 42;
if(cubicft < 2500){
    price = 0;
}else{
    price = price
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateCombustibleMaterialFireFee(cubicft){
var price;
    switch (true) {
      case cubicft < 2500: 
        price=0;
        break;

      case cubicft > 5000:
        price = 42 + (cubicft-5000)/1000*22; 
        break;

      default:
        price = 42;
        break;
   }

  // Change the parameters to the correct fee code, fee schedule, etc.
  // updateFee(fcode, fsched, fperiod, fqty, finvoice, pDuplicate, pFeeSeq)
  updateFee("FPERMIT47","FIRE","FINAL",price,"N","N");

  logDebug("$" + price);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateCombustibleMaterialFireFee(cubicft) {
var price;

if (cubicft < 2500) {
price = 0;
}
else if (cubicft > 5000) {
price = 42 + (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
}
else {
price = 42;
}

updateFee("FPERMIT47", "FIRE", "FINAL", price, "N", "N");
logDebug("$" + price);
}
```